# Changing parameter of function call in ELF executable

Tags: linux, elf

I want to alter a ELF executable function call and replace one of it's parameters.
The executable calls `dlopen()` function and passes `RTLD_NOW` as the flag parameter.
I want to change it to `RTLD_LAZY`.

What's the easiest way to detect the exact place where this call is done, and replacing the parameter.

I have to do it on production environment, so I only have GNU toolchain, gcc, gdb, etc.

Comment: Are you talking about permanently patching the executable or modifying at run time?

Comment: Both. At runtime to test it. And then persist it.

Comment: Theoretically `LD_PRELOAD` would be your friend, but given that `dlopen` is implemented within the loader, it's possible that this approach would fail.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is with [gdb](/questions/tagged/gdb). Put a breakpoint on the `dlopen` function, and change the parameters (likely passed on the stack). `RTLD_NOW` is defined as 2. Simply change it by 1 (`RTLD_LAZY`).

To sum up, in `gdb`

```
breakpoint dlopen
run
set stack_memory_address = 1
continue
```

Where `stack_memory_address` is the address of your mode parameter.

Comment: How do I save it, is it possible from gdb ?

Comment: You can use an hex-editor, seek to the offset that you broke on in GDB, and change the 2 in a 1.